# Can't get hook_civicrm_contact_get_displayname to work

Tags: hooks

I want to append a custom field to the display name.  To try it, I used the example.

```
function ccas_hooks_civicrm_contact_get_displayname(&$displayname,  $contactId, $objContact) {
$displayname = $displayname . ' - '.$contactId;}
```

No errors but what I see on the View Contact form doesn't change.

I added a watchdog thing after it

```
watchdog('hooks',"callhooks_civicrm_get_(&\$fields, &\$files, &\$form)<pre>\n\$display_name=" . var_export($displayname,1) . "\n\$contactId=" . var_export($contactId,1) . "\n\$objContact=" . var_export($objContact,1) . '</pre>');
```

In the log I can see it appending the contact id after the display name but still it only shows the name.  So do I need to do something additionally to actually get it to show it on the form?

Currently using 4.5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you modify, CRM/Utils/Hook.php

```
  public static function alterDisplayName($displayName, $contactId, $dao) {
```

and change it to

```
  public static function alterDisplayName(&$displayName, $contactId, $dao) {
```

(note the & character before the displayName argument. I suspect this will fix the issue.

If it does, can you please file an issue and if you can create a PR to fix this issue. If not, you can reference this thread

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed it.  I thought I was off in the weeds.  In the morning I'll figure out how to file and issue and create a PR.

Comment: Created issue CRM-16528 for this.

Comment: I think I created a PR.  Not sure if I did it right.